# Can you update thousands of records in core data without loading them in memory?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data

If I have thousands of records, is it possible to update a boolean flag on all the records without loading them to memory?

If not, is it possible to connect to sqlite directly to do this?

Say my model has a IsNew boolean flag that I need to update on 10000 records, I don't want to load them all in memory to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data's default persistence store is just a regular SQLite database, so it shouldn't be too hard to directly connect to that and execute your queries. I am not sure if you need to "refresh" the managed object context after you do that, but you probably should.

In an iPhone simulator, you should typically find the SQLite database under:

```
/Users/<username>/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<iOS version>/Applications/<GUID>/Documents
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but not in one go.
Just load a set number of items each time (N), update them, save, fetch the next batch.

In you example it should look something like:

```
NSFetchRequest* request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"YourEntity"];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isNew == YES"]];
[request setFetchLimit:100];
[request setIncludesPropertyValues:YES];
[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
NSArray* batch = nil;
do {
    batch = [context executeFetchRequest:request
                                   error:&error];
    if ([batch count]) {
        [batch setValue:@NO forKey:@"isNew"];
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            batch = nil;
        } else {
            [context reset]; //free memory
        }
    }
} while ([batch count] == batchSize);
//test for errors (batch == nil)
```

You will probably want to do this in the background and merge changes to the main context.

Comment: hi, but the point is I don't want to load them all and make this update, it should be a simple update statement like: `update products set isNew=false;` and then reload the context.

Comment: There is no way to do that with core data, you don't have direct access to your database.

Comment: using SQLite directly is not going through the core data stack, and you cannot rely on Apple's implementation to stay consistent. you might be able to achieve something similar by using lightweight migration twice (once to remove the `isNew` column and the second to recreate it with default value set to YES), but I have never tried it myself.